# Framemaker TOC Layout

Tags: documentation, framemaker

I have a book in Adobe Framemaker and created a TOC. The Problem now is that I can't assign my master page to my body page. Also the TOC doesn't contain any of my paragraph and character formats. Thx for help.
eactor

P.S. If I start a new chapter in a new file, normally i just copy the old one, so I retain my paragraph and character formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Framemaker takes first chapter in the book, which was my title page and provides only those referencepages within it!! So the first chapter has to contain the reference page you want to use in your TOC.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of FrameMaker are you using? Normally you can apply a Master page to the TOC page you are using. To change the format of the TOC you have to edit the TOC in the Reference page. Apply your format to the style at the bottom of the Reference pages including tabs and leader characters. Then your TOC will be formatted the way you design.

Comment: it was framemaker 8, i switched to Latex so

Comment: you awnser is correct for the text formatting, but not for the page format, which is given by the used reference page, which can't be assigned in case of the toc and are used from the chapter before